# Python Removing Punctuations in a Text using REGEX

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a Json file, specifically the text under 'context' (see in code).

As you can see in the code, I am using 3 while loops just to do it for 3 of the cases. and I am wondering if there is any better way to achieve this.

```
]['content'] = trans
            segments.append(jsondata[i])
    jsondata = segments
```

Also I would like to know if there is a way to remove double spaces and make it a single space.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that we want an expression to pass everything except for the <kbd>space</kbd> followed by a list of punctuation chars, as well as newlines.

Maybe, let's start with:

```
([\s\S].*?)(\s,|\s\.|\s!|\s\?|\s;|\s:|\s\|)?
```

where we can have two capturing groups. The first one passes everything, and the second one excludes a list of instances separated by logical ORs, which can be also simplified, if we wish.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rZYTnV/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize expressions.

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet is just to show that the expression might be valid:

```js
const regex = /([\s\S].*?)(\s,|\s\.|\s!|\s\?|\s;|\s:|\s\|)?/gm;
const str = `Start with some text Hello ? World ! Hello , World . Hello ; World | Hello : Hello? World! Hello, World. Hello; World| Hello:Hello ? World ! Hello , World . Hello ; World | Hello : Hello? World! Hello, World. Hello; World| Hello: and some other text after`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([\s\S].*?)(\s,|\s\.|\s!|\s\?|\s;|\s:|\s\|)?"

test_str = "Start with some text Hello ? World ! Hello , World . Hello ; World | Hello : Hello? World! Hello, World. Hello; World| Hello:Hello ? World ! Hello , World . Hello ; World | Hello : Hello? World! Hello, World. Hello; World| Hello: and some other text after"

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score -1):

To do the regex part:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hello ? World !'
>>> re.sub('\s+(?=[.,?!])','',s)
'Hello? World!'
>>>
```